# How can I create an application with resizeable frames

Tags: c#

How can I create an app in one window with multiple frames.

For example if i want the lower portion of the screen to be taken up by a webbrowser object, and the top split into two  halves with different items in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [SplitContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.aspx). and then [Use_the_SplitContainer](http://en.csharp-online.net/Use_the_SplitContainer)

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Wow what a great site this is! Thanks to all that answered :)

Answer (score 1):

For a single frame with several panes you can look at the [Splitter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitter.aspx) control.  When used the the dock property of Child controls you can control how they stack and move around.  You may also look at [MDI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx) patterns, but MDI is not used as much with newer applications.

Answer (score 1):

There is a SplitContainer control that would allow you to do what you want.  You want a Horizontal one, with a web browser control in the bottom, and another SplitContainer in the top with the splitter set to Vertical, then you can put your other 2 controls in the left and right side of that.